# Error when deploying Sitecore and SXA module to Azure through Visual Studio Team Services release

Tags: sxa, azure, deployment, module, arm-template

We are trying to deploy Sitecore and the SXA module to our Azure Web App through VSTS with ARM templates instead of using the powershell script from the Sitecore Azure Toolkit.

The initial Sitecore instance deploys correctly through the ARM templates, without additional modules.
We are using the *Azure Resource Group Deployment* task in VSTS to deploy the ARM templates.

After the intial deployment succeeded, we have added the bootloader and SXA modules to the ARm templates as described by Sitecores docs, which results in several errors during operations on the database. A lot of operations succeed, however, only a few operations seem to fail with a *"bad request"* error without detailed information of what is going wrong.

Has anyone succeeded to deploy additional Sitecore modules to an Azure Web App by using the VSTS Release or any clue why most of the operations on the database succeed and only some of the operations on the database fail?

Comment: In SXA we never try this approach, deployment using only ARM templates works fine. I will forward your question to Cloud team, maybe someone there known the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it's related to VSTS Release, to make sure of that: could you reproduce the exact same process by invoking for example locally this PowerShell command: `New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment` twice (according your explanation). You should be able to reproduce the same error according to me. You could invoke this command with a `-Verbose` to have some logs locally. On the `Resource Group` itself ([for example via the Azure portal](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-deployment-operations#portal)) you could have access to the history of the deployments on it, it's here you could have more detailed error messages.

Furthermore, I don't know if it's related to your error, but [here is a new PR on the official Sitecore ARM Templates repo talking about](https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore-Azure-Quickstart-Templates/pull/16):

> Deploying sxa and the bootloader on azure using the modules are handled in parallel by default...
>   ...When deploying MSDeploy packages concurrent a Bad Request: Conflict is
>   thrown during the deployment.

Maybe related to your problem?